# R markdown rticles package pnas template not knitting

Tags: r, latex, tinytex

I have been using the `rticles` package in R for a couple years now and been able to work through most issues that have come up. Now I've encountered a problem that I cannot figure out.

The problem happens when I try to knit to the `pnas_article` template. When I try to do this, I get this:

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd
|.................................................................| 100%
ordinary text without R code


"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Untitled.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output Untitled.tex --template "C:\Users\bensc\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rticles\rmarkdown\templates\pnas_article\resources\template.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --filter pandoc-citeproc 
output file: Untitled.knit.md

tlmgr search --file --global "/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install pgf
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: pgf
tlmgr search --file --global "/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Error: Failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I am using R version 3.6.1. and `tinytex`. I have followed yihui's suggestion of updating `tlmgr` (by running `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`).

Also, note that 1) the document I am trying to knit is just the default out-of-the-box pnas template file that comes with `rticles`; and 2) knitting to other default templates such as `elsevier_article` is working fine.